# Rigify: how to regenerate rig without losing animation data?

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

According to Rigify's [Doc](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/introduction.html):

> Nondisruptive re-rig If the generated rig doesn’t fit all the features
> you need or, for example, you decide to add something more to your
> character (like a sixth arm or a tail), you can re-generate your rig
> **without losing your previously generated features and your animation**
> **data.**

But what does this exactly mean? I tried this simple finger pose:

[image]

And I regenerate rig from my metarig. All the animation data is gone:

[image]

How can I re-rig without losing my animation data?

Comment: you will be able to use the same actions as long as bones keep the same names

Comment: @moonboots ok... so it's literally just as "nondisruptive" as a manual rig...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer it myself. Rigify doesn't have any "magic" in this sense. It generates an armature in a predicable way, and that's it. One needs to store the poses in pose library (or in case of full animation, create a new NLA track and stash it).